# How do I start activity B from fragment A in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

com.udacity.shoestore:

MainActivity
ShoeListActivity2
ShoeListFragment2
WelcomeFragment
InstructionsFragment

Layout:

activity_main
activity_shoe_list2
fragment_instructions
fragment_login
fragment_shoe_list2
fragment_welcome

manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ShoeListActivity2"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_shoe_list2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

From the instructions fragment, I am trying to start the ShoeListActivity fragment but it crashes.  While trying to debug, it tries to load up the MainActivity.

First I tried

```
    binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent=Intent(this@InstructionsFragment, this@ShoeListActivity2)
        startActivity(intent)    
    }
```

but the IDE wouldn't accept it as an intent.

Then I found out that it would like Intent to be something like

```
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_MAIN)
    startActivity(intent, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
```

but it didn't like that either. So I tried

```
    binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

But that just ended up trying to go to the main activity before crashing.

What is the right way to start the ShoeListActivity2 from the InstructionsFragment?

Thanks. PS:  I also tried

```
    binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@InstructionsFragment, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

but the editor flagged this as an error as "Intent" was underlined in red.

Comment: try requireActivity as first parameter on Intent constructor:
Intent(requireActivity, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)

Comment: Thank you, this might have worked but I since decided that I will try to get the navigation feature to work.

Comment: Yeah, I really recommend you to try that component. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get Context of the parent Activity, Because Fragment doesn't have its own Context

You can do something like this:

```
val intent = Intent (getActivity(), ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

your trying for following code is almost correct

```
binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(context, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

but here "context" is nullable object which IDE would be giving error as Intent's constructor params requires Context to be not Null. So ideally we need to pass context with null safety. We can do it in following 2 ways:

1: Using null safety using let scope

```
binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
    context?.let{
       val intent = Intent(it, ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
    }        
}
```

2: Using in-built requiredContext or requireActivity function with try-catch

```
binding.listShoesButton.setOnClickListener {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), ShoeListActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch(e : IllegalStateException){
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it still crashed although it was syntactically correct.  I am going to try to get the navigation working as I believe that is a much cleaner solution than using intents.  Thank you.